# Is there a way to know which components got updated upon action

Tags: jsf, primefaces, rerender

When programming in JSF 2.2 I'm sometimes unsure if the `update` statement worked or not. For example, I have the table below and want it to get updated when the button i clicked:

```
<h:form id="theform">

    <h:panelGroup id="entity">

        <p:dataTable
            var="item"
            tableStyle="width:auto"
            styleClass="tableFillRight"
            value="#{artistEntityBean.asList}"
            id="table">

            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" styleClass="tableArtistName" />
            </p:column>

            <f:facet name="footer">

                <h:panelGroup id="footerWrapper">

                    <p:commandButton
                        id="requestMod"
                        partialSubmit="true"
                        process="@this"
                        value="become moderator"
                        update="@parent :messages"
                        disabled="#{moderatorEntityBean.item.moderatingArtist}"
                        actionListener="#{moderatorEntityBean.handleCreate()}"
                        action="#{artistEntityBean.init()}">                            
                    </p:commandButton>

                </h:panelGroup>

            </f:facet>

        </p:dataTable>

    </h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```

As the `ID` of the button is `theForm:table:requestMod` I thought that `update="@parent"` would work. However, it does not seem to get updated, or maybe I've made a mistake somewhere in the backing bean or somewhere else?

The thing is: I do not now. So in order to deduce where the error lies, it would have been great to somehow really make sure that the `update` part of the `commandButton` worked.

As it is now, when the button is clicked, the changed value is only updated after reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Firebug` or similar browser plugin to monitor network and check response from the server. If component (for example, clientId=component_client_id) is updated you will see something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <changes>
        <update id="component_client_id">
            <![CDATA[
                ... component's HTML code ...
            ]]>
         </update>
        <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">
             <![CDATA[-74243231543289530:-219780152641895389]]>
        </update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```